# Sum of a row of a character table.

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I am given the following question : Let $G$ be a finite group and $\chi$ an irreducible character. What is $\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)?$

This is the sum of a row of the table character. I know the orthogonality relations but I never read that the sum of the rows in a character table are something particular.

Comment: Use the row orthogonality relation. (Since it's a one-line statement, anything more than that gives the answer.)

Comment: Maybe it's [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_table)?

Comment: Google finds [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/349221)

Comment: [This](https://equatorialmaths.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/row-sums-of-character-tables/) seems relevant. Did you even *do* a search?

Comment: Have you tried computing any examples? There'll be a pretty clear pattern.

Comment: If I consider the action of $G$ on itself by permutation (i.e. the $\mathbb{C}G$-module $\mathbb{C}G$ with the action $g\cdot h = ghg^{-1}$), then the corresponding character is $\chi(g)=\vert \{h:ghg^{-1}=h\}\vert=\vert C_G(g)\vert$. So if I take an irreducible character (should it be irreducible?) $\chi'$, then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^l \chi'(g_i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^l\frac{\chi(g_i^{-1})}{\vert C_G(g_i)\vert}\chi'(g_i)=\frac{1}{\vert G\vert}\sum\limits_{i=1}^l\vert C_i \vert \chi (g_i^{-1})\chi'(g_i)=(\chi,\chi')$. I am not sure where I use the row orthogonal relations?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven how do you  do this in one line?

Comment: Ah, this would be another valid answer I guess. So perhaps there are 2 answers. One is that the sum is the scalar product of the character with the trivial character. The other answer is that the sum is the multiplicity of the character for which we sum inside the decomposition of the character of the action by conjugation.

Comment: Except only one of those two answers is true.